# json encode php showing strange characters

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I've tried the following:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "dsds", "dsds");
mysql_select_db('dsdasds');
$sqlquery = "select * from discounts";
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$result = mysql_query( $sqlquery, $conn );
if(! $result )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

/*
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['name'];
} 
*/

$dataArray = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $dataArray[] = $r;
}

print json_encode($dataArray);
?>
```

and I get the following output:

```
[{"0":"\u0628\u0631\u0628\u0631\u064a ","name":"\u0628\u0631\u0628\u0631\u064a ","1":"55","rate":"55","2":"\u0627\u0644\u0631\u0627\u0634\u062f ","location":"\u0627\u0644\u0631\u0627\u0634\u062f ","3":"68","id":"68","4":"\u0627\u0644\u062e\u0628\u0631","city":"\u0627\u0644\u062e\u0628\u0631","5":"","duration":"","6":"","category":""}]
```

The data is correct but as you can see not readable. What can I do to solve this issue? It should show arabic words not what it is showing now

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a special encoding to have readable json result of arabic character (unicode).

You can specify otherwise with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE PHP 5.4 or later.

```
json_encode('yourarabiccharacters', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Now I can't see anything at all.

Comment: Try changing your header to header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'');

Comment: this test works for me $value = 'معاً';
echo json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// Outputs: "معاً"  there might be something else.....

Comment: working now! thought I had php 5.4 on this server but it was on another service. just changed that and it all worked! thanks again :)